# I want to show the salary of employee in textbox whenever the employee selected from combobox

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

```
  public void GET_Salary()
  {
      string query = "Select Salary from Employee_Finance Where 
          Employee_Name = @Employee_Name";
      SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
      sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_Name", 
          (object)Employeename_comboBox.SelectedItem ?? DBNull.Value);
      DataTable data = new DataTable();
      sda.Fill(data);
      if (data.Rows.Count > 0)
      {
          int salary = Convert.ToInt32(data.Rows[0]["Salary"]);
          salarytextBox.Text = salary.ToString();
      }
  }
```

//but when i select the employee it didnot show his salary

Comment: Do you have an event defined on your combo box that you are expecting to fire? Does the event trigger? Does that even call this method? So little information given here and so many possibilities about why this "doesn't work".

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Side note: do not cache your connection object, create when needed and dispose with `using`

Answer (score 0):

call your GET_Salary() function inside the **SelectionChangeCommitted** Event and get the selected value of your combobox like this:

```
string _Employee_Name=Employeename_comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

full code:

```
private void cmbNationalCode_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    string _Employee_Name=Employeename_comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
             GET_Salary( _Employee_Name );
        }

  public void GET_Salary( string  Employee_Name)
  {
      string query = "Select Salary from Employee_Finance Where 
          Employee_Name = @Employee_Name";
      SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
      sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_Name",    Employee_Name ?? DBNull.Value);
      DataTable data = new DataTable();
      sda.Fill(data);
      if (data.Rows.Count > 0)
      {
          int salary = Convert.ToInt32(data.Rows[0]["Salary"]);
          salarytextBox.Text = salary.ToString();
      }
  }
```